# Cannot delete File in use by read stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to delete a folder after a POST request but i can't because it's in use by a read stream. I tried `.destroy();` and `.unpipe();` but it's still in use.

I declare my read stream variable globally so i can destroy and unpipe it out of scope.

```
var file;
```

Here my Read Stream Function :

```
app.get('/api/video/:folder' , function(req, res) {
  var streamer = req.params.folder
  const path = 'D:/Clips/' + folder + '/clip.mp4'
  const stat = fs.statSync(path)
  const fileSize = stat.size
  const range = req.headers.range

  if (range) {
    const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")
    const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10)
    const end = parts[1]
      ? parseInt(parts[1], 10)
      : fileSize-1

    const chunksize = (end-start)+1
    //const file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start, end})
    file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start, end})
    const head = {
      'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
      'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
      'Content-Length': chunksize,
      'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    }

    res.writeHead(206, head)
    file.pipe(res)
  } else {
    const head = {
      'Content-Length': fileSize,
      'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    }
    res.writeHead(200, head)
    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res)
  }
});
```

and here is my delete request :

```
app.post('/api/delete', urlencodedParser, function(req,res){
  file.unpipe();
  file.destroy();
  var delFolder = req.body.folder;
  fsextra.removeSync('D:/Clips/' + delFolder);
});
```

It's giving me error because the file is in use by read stream.

How can i end read stream process ?

Comment: which version of node are you using? `destroy` should definitely work. Perhaps you could try to call `removeSync` from a setTimeout, in case `destroy` doesn't clear the stream right away.